# How to retrieve more than one json encode from one ajax call?

Tags: jquery, json

For example I have this ajax function but I can call only one json here what code to add to be able to get more than 1 json:

```
var blue_name = $("#blue_team #blue_name").val().trim();
            var blue_type = $("#blue_team #blue_type").val().trim();
            var red_name = $("#red_team #red_name").val().trim();
            var red_type = $("#red_team #red_type").val().trim();
            $.ajax({
                url: "battle_review.php",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                data: { bname: blue_name
                btype: blue_type
                rname: red_name
                rtype: red_type},
                success:function(data){
                    var toAppend = '';
                    if(typeof data === "object"){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            //append data here
                        }
                        $("#table1").append(toAppend);// first json
                    }
                }
            });
```

And here's my php code and how I put data on my json I want is that i can get the two json's $blue and $red How to do that?:

```
    //get blue_team attributes
$blue = array();

$blue_result = $db->dataWarrior($battle,$name);

foreach($blue_result as $warrior){
    $blue[] = $names;
}



//get red_team attributes
$red = array();

$red_result = $db->dataWarrior($battle,$name);

foreach($red_result as $warrior){
    $red[] = $names;
}

echo json_encode(array('red'=>$red,'blue'=>$blue));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve more than one array on one single AJAX call? Just make... an array of array!

Instead of two `json_encode` call, just put:

```
echo json_encode(array('red' => $red, 'blue' => $blue));
```

Then, in your Javascript code, you can access them via `data.blue` and `data.red`.

Comment: +1, or he can just use a separator if two jsons merged seem hard to work with.

Comment: A separator between two JSON-encoded arrays? That seems to be even more complex: return value is not a valid JSON string and you cannot use jQuery JSON *datatype*.

Comment: Use my initial answer, I was just replying to Shaheer suggestion.

Comment: didnt get any output but when I use the firebug I can see the values